# Python: Check Next List in Nested List

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

```
month = [[0,1,0,1,0,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

each nested list corresponds to a week and
each `1` corresponds to an "event" and each event has a random length between 2-14
**Example:**
I want to enter the event at `month[0][5]` with a length of 6 days
how do I make it so that the next 6 days all the "events" (including the events that cross the current week) turn 0?

**Expected Output:**

```
month = [[0,1,0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

Comment: and what do you want in case next 6 days are not available like user selected month[3][5] ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi so the whole month is actually generated through a function, and in the function it checks if the event's length is more than the days left of the month, in that case the events length is shortened to the days left, I actually made it so that at month[4][6} there can't be an event.

Comment: you can simply try it by your own. This can be done. If you are not able to do then reproduce your code here we will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
week, day = 0, 5 #starting point eg: month[0][5]
event_days = 6
for _ in range(event_days):
    week, day = (week + 1, 0) if day == len(month[week])-1 else (week, day + 1)
    month[week][day] = 0
```

output:

```
>>
[
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was talking to myself about how easy the problem is. I've been programming for 4 hours straight and I think there was a mental block that prevented me to come up with a solution. Tysm!

Comment: I would if I could, Apparently I need 15 reps to cast a vote But hey, once I get there I'll comeback here

Answer (score 0):

You can run a nested for loop starting from i = 0 and j =5 and let it run until j = 7 at that point increment i by 1. and loop until you complete iterations equal to the length of the event while replacing the values with 0.

```
    month[0][5] = 6
    for i in range(0,len(month)):
       for j in range(6,8):
          month[i][j] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of representing a month as a nested list you could also flatten your month into days. With this list most operations should be much more simple. Whenever needed you can simple select a week by `days[7*week:7*(week+1)]`

```
days = [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]

# set an event
event_week = 0
event_day_of_week = 5
event_days = 6

event_begin = 7 * event_week + event_day_of_week + 1
event_end = event_begin + event_days
days[event_begin:event_end] = [0] * event_days

# get a week
week_begin = 1*7
week_end = 2*7
second_week = days[week_begin:week_end]

print(second_week)
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```